# Regular pause in conjunction with random timer

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 http request. Namely the below:

1. Register client - register only for one time.
2. Health check - perform this every 10 minutes.
3. Create event - randomly perform this.

My jmeter structure as below:

> ```
> + Register client HTTP REQUEST
> + Loop forever
>   + Health check HTTP REQUEST
>   + Interval SIMPLE CONTROLLER
>     + Pause 10 minutes TEST ACTION
>   + Create event HTTP REQUEST
> ```

However, i could achieve the purpose to perform health check every 10 minutes but i can't find a way to insert a random timer to achieve the create event randomly. When i insert the random timer into Interval SIMPLE CONTROLLER, it will affect the health check HTTP REQUEST as the wait interval will become pause 10 minutes + random timer.

Anyone has any clue to achieve what i want to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching from Test Action sampler to [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer). Scope of the Constant Timer can be limited to one Sampler only.

Remember one thing: Timers are executed **before** samplers

You can re-use the same approach for your `Create Event` request, however instead of static value of `600000` milliseconds you can put something varying there, i.e. [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) article for all JMeter timers explained.

Comment: How could i achieve to put the two request in one LOOP but one with constant timer and one with random timer and the two requests should be independent from each other.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wanna have random pauses in your forever loop, so to achieve this put all bellow forever loop into Simpler Controller and before it add your Random Timer. Something like this:

> ```
> + Register client HTTP REQUEST
> + Loop forever
>     + Health check HTTP REQUEST
>     + Interval SIMPLE CONTROLLER
>       + Pause 10 minutes TEST ACTION
>   + Simple Controller
>     + Random Timer
>     + Create event HTTP REQUEST
> ```

Timer will apply only to HTTP Request in the Simple Controller, not each element of the Forever Loop.

Comment: i want something like

10:00 health check
10:10 health check
10:15 create event (random)
10:20 health check

Comment: I edited the answer to be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: The simple controller is inside the LOOP FOREVER , right? using your answer, won't it be 10:00 health check 10:10 health check 10:15 create event (random) 10:25 health check? Will try implement to see the result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Best thing is to try and see it yourself. For random delay you could use [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer).

Comment: Tried.  The result is 10:00 health check 10:10 health check 10:15 create event (random) 10:25 health check. Which is not what i want to achieve. Anyway, thanks for your prompt reply.